# Control compression of html file when packaging UWP app as an APPX

Tags: .net, windows-store-apps, uwp, makeappx

I'm looking for documentation for how to change the compression for HTML files using the makeappx.exe tool https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446767(v=vs.85).aspx

When running the makeappx pack /v I can see in the logs something like:

```
Settings for extension html: Type = text/html, Compression = Normal.
Adding "C:\SNIP\Content\StartPage.html" to the package as a payload file.  Its path in the package is "Content\StartPage.html".
```

What I'd like is to do is set the Compression to "None". (because it's removing the Cariage returns and corrupting the Mark-Of-The-Web in the StartPage.html.) I can't find any documentation for how to do this though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I'd like is to do is set the Compression to "None".

If you type `makeappx pack /?` you will see there is a `/nc` option, which will prevent the tool from compressing the files:
[image]

So the command will be `makeappx pack /v /nc`.